# Google maps JSON markers load asynchronously?

Tags: json, google-maps, asynchronous, google-maps-api-3

I found some code to load Google Map marker data from a JSON file here: http://snippetrepo.com/snippets/multiple-markers-using-json-with-google-maps-api

It's working great, but I am getting a warning in the developer console:

```
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
```

I did some research on this issue and it appears that the problem is that this code has `'async': false`. I tried to just change that value to `true` but then I was getting another error with my function that displays the closest results to the user, because the marker array was empty when that function fired.

Is it possible to make this work asynchronously? Is there anything wrong with disabling async?

```
var json = (function () { 
    var json = null; 
    $.ajax({ 
        'async': false, 
        'global': false, 
        'url': "js/hotels.json", 
        'dataType': "json", 
        'success': function (data) {
             json = data; 
         }
    });
    return json;
})();
```

Comment: `async: false` it's a bad idea since it freezes the UI. When you change it to true, the function is called async so the next JS line is `return json;` which will be empty because ajax is still running. You need to return or continue after `success()`

Comment: The maps-API already has a method to create markers(and other features) via JSON, take a look at the [Data Layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer)